# Undefined Step Definitions when Running Cucumber scripts in command line

Tags: ruby, command-line, cucumber

I was previously using RubyMine to run cucumber test scripts and it works just fine, but I am looking for an alternative to run those scripts from command line.

When I try to run a specific .feature file from cmd, I get an error stating that my Ruby step definitions are undefined. I am assuming this is because they are not located in the same directory as the .feature file that I am trying to run.

Here is my cmd output:
[Undefined Steps error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXP8l.png)

Any suggestions welcome! Thanks

Comment: Please don't post screenshots.  Cut/paste the error code into the question with appropriate formatting.

Comment: PLease  share your runner class

Answer (score 0):

If you're running `cucumber` from `your_directory`. Then your `.feature` files should be in `your_directory/features` and step definitions (`.rb` files) in `your_directory/features/step_definitions` Subfolders are supported.

Look at https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

If you're running Win10, check [WSL](https://www.linux.com/blog/learn/2018/2/how-get-started-using-wsl-windows-10) - makes your life better ;-)